# Use window object from JS lib in React Typescript project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack

Having a fresh new project in React and Typescript, I need to use a JS Lib developed by my fellow colleagues.

The lib is packaged and added to the project with NPM.
The content of the min.js is like:

```js
window.SharedObj=function(e){
...
}
```

So, this lib is designed to register an instance of SharedObj at the window scope, and I need to retrieve this instance in my top level component (index.tsx).

I've successufully done it this way:

```js
require('path/lib.min.js');

// @ts-ignore
new SharedObj();

if ((window as any).SharedObj) {
    ReactDOM.render(
        <React.StrictMode>
            <App/>
        </React.StrictMode>,
        document.getElementById('root')
    );
}
```

This works, but it seems wrong to me to ts-ignore and "as any" in order to make this work.

Do you have a better solution ?
May I extend the Window definition ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can declare the **Window** object globally as an interface with `SharedObj` being one of it's property.

```
declare global {
  interface Window {
    // you'll need to explicitly specify the
    // type of arguments & function return type
    SharedObj: (e: ArgsType) => ReturnType;
  }
}
```